# regex to exclude filename from url

Tags: php, regex

I require a regex that will exclude file name from URL.

Input: `'something.something.com/som/som/som/abcd.html'`

Should return: `'something.something.com/som/som/som/'`

I created this regex:

`((?:[a-z0-9\.\_]+)(?:\/)(?:.*?)(?:\/))(?:[a-z0-9]+)(?:\.)(?:[a-z0-9]+)`

I tried whatever I can and it is giving correct output (tested at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) [PCRE]).

Do I need to add/delete anything else? Any more suggestions? And don't suggest to use `parse_url()`, it is useless if URL don't have 'http://'.

Comment: That's why you check for `//:` and add `'http://` is not found.

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver for edits. Will take care about it next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP:

```
$dir = dirname("something.something.com/som/som/som/abcd.html");
```

Using regex:

```
$dir = preg_replace("|[^/]+\.[^/]+$|", "$1", $dir);
```

Comment: Yes, regex is an excellent thing, but it can fail for some particular cases. That's why its better to use functions like that, which are dedicated for a special purpose.